# How to test for significance for binomial count data where the expected outcome is unknown?

Tags: chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, dice

**Description of the data:**

The study is investigating whether conversations on a messaging app are greater or less than 8 words long. The variable is the count of messages that contain more than 8 words (≤8 = TRUE, >8=FALSE).

**count based on orginal data**

| Outcome | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | 29 |
| FALSE | 31 |

**original data**

[image]

**How to test this?**

Would you use a chi-squared goodness of fit test to evaluate if these results are due to random chance. I have a inkling that the chi squared goodness of fit is the best test (as in for rolling the dice binomial distributions) but I'm unsure about what the expected values would be.

Comment: "*(>8 = TRUE, <8=FALSE)*" ... What was supposed to happen when the length is 8?

Comment: @Glen_b A message length<8 is mean more efficient communication

Comment: I didn't ask about <8 but about =8. Do you mean to say that it should be ≤8?

Comment: @ Glen_b edited, I meant to say A message length ≤8 means more efficient communication